# ReactNative: TextInput has strange behaviour with the value-attribute on data-binding

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In a react-native app I built a form with  that can't be typed in when using the value-attribute. Every new character will be removed and the text box will be reseted to the state that was in the form before.

```
class LoginScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          username: 'nobody',
          password: '****'
        };
      }

    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                   .......
                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TextInput
                            style={[styles.input, styles.whiteFont]}
                            placeholder="Username"
                            placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
                            value={this.state.username}
                        />
```

Using this code no typing is possible. When i remove the value-attibute, everything works fine. But i'd like to use this data binding.

How can i deal with TextInput-Elements with data-binding?

**Update:**

I also tried this one, without any success:

```
                    <TextInput
                        style={[styles.input, styles.whiteFont]}
                        placeholder="Username"
                        placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
                        value={this.state.username}
                        ref= "username"
                        onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})}
                    />
```

Comment: You are setting the value to of your input on render however you are not updating it onChange therefore the state of your text input never gets updated. Try using an onChange event handler that sets state to the value of the input

Comment: The syntax of your event handler is slightly off...

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me https://rnplay.org/apps/f1nKZQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add an event handler like the following to your `TextInput` component to set state to the value a user inputs `onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})}`